# How to limit the max fontsize with sp in android

Tags: android

I just want to use "sp" in android xml file. But to avoid the disorder of layout, I hope the max font size can be set. How to do that?

Comment: The `fontSize` is not the reason why your layout behaves that way. It's the `TextView` where you probably have set `wrap_content`.

Comment: `sp` automatically takes care of the font sizes. You don't have to set a max font size.

Comment: man do not pass greater then your max value of font size, sp automatically takes care of the font sizes.

Comment: I get you, @Murat K, @ Reaz Murshed, and I just means, can I set a upper limit in my app to limit the font scale range?

Comment: Yes, `sp` does take care of font sizes, but it does not prevent the UI design from being corrupted by a large font size.